# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Last line

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

Still looking at the codes but can't find the mistake. Maybe I got slightly blind maybe I should take a little break but trying to finish up this before taking rest.
Error is given at last line.
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in ..../index.php on line 274"
Any solution or suggestion on this ?

```
    <?php
include("config.php");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_bin'");
$query = mysql_query("select * from settings");
while($print = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $print['description']; ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $print['keywords']; ?>" />    
    <meta name="author" content="-, -" />   

    <title><?php echo $print['title']; ?></title>   

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thema/default/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="thema/default/javascript/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/api.js"></script>



<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.header_category_item{
    padding:11px 14px 9px 14px !important; 
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
    <script>$(window).load(function() { $('.blueberry').blueberry(); }); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ajaxLoad").hide();

  $('.home_video').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed:  500, //Geçiş süreci
    timeout: 5000,//Geçiş Süresi
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    prev:   '.homve_video_prev', 
    next:   '.homve_video_next',
    pause: true,  


  });

    $('.home_photo').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed:  500, //Geçiş süreci
    timeout: 5000,//Geçiş Süresi
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    prev:   '.homve_photo_prev', 
    next:   '.homve_photo_next',
    pause: true, 


  });


  $('.last_min').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollVert',
    speed:  100, //Geçiş süreci
    timeout: 5000,//Geçiş Süresi
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    prev:   '.last_min_prev', 
    next:   '.last_min_next',
    pause: true, 


  });




});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#basadon").css("display","none");
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (top > 50) {
      $("#basadon").fadeIn("normal");
    }else {
      $("#basadon").fadeOut("fast");
    }
  });
  $("#basadon").click(function(){
    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal' );
  });

});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="page">



<!-- Header -->



<div class="ajaxLoad"><img src="thema/default/images/loading51.gif"></div>

<div style="position:fixed;  margin-left:-166px; margin-top:-5px; width:160px; overflow:hidden;">
</div>
<div style="position:fixed; margin-left:997px; margin-top:-5px; width:160px; overflow:hidden;">
</div>



<div style="height:35px;  margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:-5px; font-weight:bold; color:#036; background-color:#F0F0F0; font-size:12px;">
<div class="header_general_menu_item"><a href="index<?php echo $print['seourl']; ?>">Anasayfa</a></div>
<?php $ggg = mysql_query("select * from pages order by sira asc"); while($hhh = mysql_fetch_array($ggg)){ if($print['seourl']==".php"){ ?>
<div class="header_general_menu_item"><a href="pages.php?url=<?php echo $hhh['sefurl']; ?>"><?php echo $hhh['baslik']; ?></a></div>
<?php }elseif($print['seourl']==".html"){ ?>
<div class="header_general_menu_item"><a href="sayfa-<?php echo $hhh['sefurl']; ?>.html"><?php echo $hhh['baslik']; ?></a></div>

<div class="header_general_menu_item" style="float:right; padding:2px;"><form action="http://www.ersoyotomotiv.org/search.php" method="get">
<input style="margin-top:2px; margin-right:3px; border:#EAEAEA 1px solid; height:22px; padding:3px; width:240px; font-style:italic; color:#999" type="text" name="s" value="Haber Ara" onFocus="if(this.value=='Haber Ara')this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Haber Ara';"/><input type="submit" value=" Ara " style="width:50px; height:27px; margin-top:-1px; border:0px; background-color:#C00; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px;" /></form></div>


</div>



<div class="logo"><a href="index<?php echo $print['seourl']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="<?php echo $print['title']; ?>" width="247" height="90" border="0"  /></a></div>

<div class="header_advert">
<script async src="../pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/f.txt"></script>
<!-- En üstteki Reklam -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1212664113367830"
     data-ad-slot="8895001303"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>

<div class="clear"></div>


<div class="header_top_menu"></div>

<div class="header_category">
<div class="mask">
<?php if($print['seourl']==".php"){ $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc"); while($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)){ $urx = $ddd['sefurl']; ?>
<div class="header_category_item"><a href="emkat.php?url=<?php echo $ddd['sefurl']; ?>">><?php echo $ddd['baslik']; ?></a></div>
<?php $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
<div class="header_category_item"><a href="emkat.php?url=<?php echo $ddx['sefurl']; ?>"><?php echo $ddx['baslik']; ?></a></div>
<?php } ?></li><?php } }elseif($print['seourl']==".html"){ $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc"); while($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)){ $urx = $ddd['sefurl']; ?>
<div class="header_category_item"><a href="kategori-<?php echo $ddd['sefurl']; ?>.html"><?php echo $ddd['baslik']; ?></a></div>
<?php $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
<div class="header_category_item"><a href="kategori-<?php echo $ddx['sefurl']; ?>.html"><?php echo $ddx['baslik']; ?></a></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<!-- End Header -->





<div>
<!-- Content -->

<div class="news_boxs">


<?php if($print['seourl']==".php"){ ?>      
<div class="php_news_box"  style="margin:10px 20px; position:relative"><a href="emlakdetail.php?url=<?php echo $fff['sefurl']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $fff['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fff['baslik']; ?>" width="227" height="157" title="<?php echo $fff['baslik']; ?>" /></a><br>
            <?php }elseif($print['seourl']==".html"){ ?>
            <a href="emlak-<?php echo $fff['sefurl']; ?>.html"><img src="<?php echo $fff['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fff['baslik']; ?>" width="227" height="157" title="<?php echo $fff['baslik']; ?>" /></a><br>
            <?php } ?>

     <table width="100%" class="detail_home" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <?php $asd1 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['anakat']."'"); while($asd2 = mysql_fetch_array($asd1)){ echo $asd2['baslik']; } echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  
        $asd3 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['altkat']."'"); while($asd4 = mysql_fetch_array($asd3)){ echo $asd4['baslik']; } ?><br>
        <p><?php echo $fff['il']; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $fff['ilce']; ?></p><?php } ?>
  <tr>
    <td width="27%"><strong>Fiyat</strong></td>
    <td width="2%"><strong>:</strong></td>
    <td width="71%"><?php echo number_format($fff['fiyat']); ?> TL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong><?php if($print['seourl']==".php"){ ?>          
                    <a href="emlakdetail.php?url=<?php echo $fff['sefurl']; ?>">Ayrıntılar</a>
                <?php }elseif($print['seourl']==".html"){ ?>
                    <a href="emlak-<?php echo $fff['sefurl']; ?>.html">Ayrıntılar</a>
                    <?php } ?></strong></td>

  </tr>

</table>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- Content -->
</div>



<!-- Footer -->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="height:35px;  margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0px; font-weight:bold; color:#036; background-color:#F0F0F0; font-size:12px;">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="margin-top:10px; background-repeat: no-repeat; border-top: #EAEAEA 2px dotted;">

<div style="float:left; width:220px; height:80px;">
<a href="index<?php echo $print['seourl']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="<?php echo $print['title']; ?>" width="220" height="80" border="0"  /></a>
</div>
<div style="padding:35px; font-size:11px;">
<strong>&copy;</strong> Copyright <?php echo date('Y'); ?>,  <strong><?php echo $print['title']; ?> </strong>. Tüm hakları saklıdır.  </div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>


<div onclick="" id="basadon" style="position: fixed; right:10px; bottom:10px; width:50px; height:50px; background-image:url(thema/default/images/top_ico.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
</div>
<!-- End Footer -->
        </div>



<script> function SayiKontrol(e) {
    olay = document.all ? window.event : e;
    tus = document.all ? olay.keyCode : olay.which;
    if(tus<48||tus>57) {
        if(document.all) { olay.returnValue = false; } else { olay.preventDefault(); }
    }
} </script> 
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` somewhere. Most IDE's would've outline that for you...

Comment: dont use a while loop if your only getting one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not balanced. If you remove everything but the PHP, then remove each pair of `<?php` `?>` other than the first and last one, and then format the code this is the result:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_bin'");
    $query = mysql_query("select * from settings");
    while ($print = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $print['description'];
        echo $print['keywords'];
        echo $print['title'];
        echo $print['seourl'];
        $ggg = mysql_query("select * from pages order by sira asc");
        while ($hhh = mysql_fetch_array($ggg)) {
            if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                echo $hhh['sefurl'];
                echo $hhh['baslik'];
            }
            elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
                echo $hhh['sefurl'];
                echo $hhh['baslik'];
                echo $print['seourl'];
                if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                    $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc");
                    while ($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)) {
                        $urx = $ddd['sefurl'];
                        echo $ddd['sefurl'];
                        echo $ddd['baslik'];
                        $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc");
                        while ($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)) {
                            echo $ddx['sefurl'];
                            echo $ddx['baslik'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
                    $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc");
                    while ($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)) {
                        $urx = $ddd['sefurl'];
                        echo $ddd['sefurl'];
                        echo $ddd['baslik'];
                        $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc");
                        while ($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)) {
                            echo $ddx['sefurl'];
                            echo $ddx['baslik'];
                        }
                        if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                            echo $fff['sefurl'];
                            echo $fff['thumb'];
                            echo $fff['baslik'];
                            echo $fff['baslik'];
                        }
                        elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
                            echo $fff['sefurl'];
                            echo $fff['thumb'];
                            echo $fff['baslik'];
                            echo $fff['baslik'];
                        }
                        $asd1 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['anakat']."'");
                        while ($asd2 = mysql_fetch_array($asd1)) {
                            echo $asd2['baslik'];
                        }
                        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  
                        $asd3 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['altkat']."'");
                        while ($asd4 = mysql_fetch_array($asd3)) {
                            echo $asd4['baslik'];
                        }
                        echo $fff['il'];
                        echo $fff['ilce'];
                    }
                    echo number_format($fff['fiyat']);
                    if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                        echo $fff['sefurl'];
                    }
                    elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
                        echo $fff['sefurl'];
                    }
                    echo $print['seourl'];
                    echo $print['title'];
                    echo date('Y');
                    echo $print['title'];
                }
?>
```

I guess one solution would be to add the remaining three `}` but you will probably have to look through the logic yourself to determine that

Below is my best guess on where the three closing curly brackets belong. Keep in mind that I have no idea what your database looks like and I did not run the code:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_bin'");
    $query = mysql_query("select * from settings");
    while ($print = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $print['description'];
        echo $print['keywords'];
        echo $print['title'];
        echo $print['seourl'];

    } // ADDED THIS CLOSING CURLY

    $ggg = mysql_query("select * from pages order by sira asc");
    while ($hhh = mysql_fetch_array($ggg)) {
        if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
            echo $hhh['sefurl'];
            echo $hhh['baslik'];
        }
        elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
            echo $hhh['sefurl'];
            echo $hhh['baslik'];
            echo $print['seourl'];
            if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc");
                while ($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)) {
                    $urx = $ddd['sefurl'];
                    echo $ddd['sefurl'];
                    echo $ddd['baslik'];

                } // ADDED THIS CLOSING CURLY

                $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc");
                while ($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)) {
                    echo $ddx['sefurl'];
                    echo $ddx['baslik'];
                }
            }
        }
        elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
            $ccc = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='' order by sira asc");
            while ($ddd = mysql_fetch_array($ccc)) {
                $urx = $ddd['sefurl'];
                echo $ddd['sefurl'];
                echo $ddd['baslik'];

            } // ADDED THIS CLOSING CURLY

            $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc");
            while ($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)) {
                echo $ddx['sefurl'];
                echo $ddx['baslik'];
            }
            if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
                echo $fff['sefurl'];
                echo $fff['thumb'];
                echo $fff['baslik'];
                echo $fff['baslik'];
            }
            elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
                echo $fff['sefurl'];
                echo $fff['thumb'];
                echo $fff['baslik'];
                echo $fff['baslik'];
            }
            $asd1 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['anakat']."'");
            while ($asd2 = mysql_fetch_array($asd1)) {
                echo $asd2['baslik'];
            }
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';  
            $asd3 = mysql_query("select * from emkat where sefurl='".$fff['altkat']."'");
            while ($asd4 = mysql_fetch_array($asd3)) {
                echo $asd4['baslik'];
            }
            echo $fff['il'];
            echo $fff['ilce'];
        }
        echo number_format($fff['fiyat']);
        if ($print['seourl']==".php") {
            echo $fff['sefurl'];
        }
        elseif ($print['seourl']==".html") {
            echo $fff['sefurl'];
        }
        echo $print['seourl'];
        echo $print['title'];
        echo date('Y');
        echo $print['title'];
    }
?>
```

The three closing brackets correspond to these lines in the code you posted:

**1**:

```
<?php $ggg = mysql_query("select * from pages order by sira asc"); while($hhh = mysql_fetch_array($ggg)){ if($print['seourl']==".php"){ ?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php } $ggg = mysql_query("select * from pages order by sira asc"); while($hhh = mysql_fetch_array($ggg)){ if($print['seourl']==".php"){ ?>
```

**2:**

```
<?php $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php } $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
```

**3** (the other one, same syntax as 2)**:**

```
<?php $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php } $ccx = mysql_query("select * from emkat where kategori='$urx' order by sira asc"); while($ddx = mysql_fetch_array($ccx)){ ?>
```